# Change tags in evernote business

Tags: python, evernote

I would like to use hierarchical tags in evernote business. In the evernote ui, I can setup hierarchies in business tags, but when I try to set the parentGuid for a business notebook tag, I only get

```
evernote.edam.error.ttypes.EDAMUserException: EDAMUserException(parameter='authenticationToken', errorCode=3)
=> PERMISSION_DENIED
```

I run this with an admin business account.

Comment:
I found out, that I can't change the name of the tag too. So the limitation is not the parentGuid, but the update itself. After creating I can't change any more.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, yeah sorry, our current service API doesn't allow updating tags in an EB account. Apologies, but no plans to change that at this time.